# Vuetify v-file-upload form reset issue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using this inside a v-form that is inside of a v-dialog:

```
    <v-file-input
        v-model="referencefile"
        clearable
        show-size
        label="Attach Reference Letter"
        @change="uploadref"
    >
    </v-file-input>
```

uploadref() Executes an upload to firebase and the upload works fine then
I submit the form it works with no errors, but when I try to reset the form using:

```
    this.$refs.form.reset();
```

I get this error in the console:

```
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <VFileInput>
           <VForm>
             <VCard>
               <VThemeProvider>
                 <VDialog>
                   <Userform>
                     <VToolbar>
                       <VSimpleTable>
                         <VData>
                           <VDataTable>
                             <Adminview> at src/views/Adminview.vue
                               <VContent>
                                 <VApp>
                                   <App> at src/App.vue
                                     <Root>
    warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
    logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
    globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
    handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1862
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
    Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888
    set @ VFileInput.ts?e8de:108
    reset @ index.ts?91bf:220
    eval @ VForm.ts?24e7:89
    reset @ VForm.ts?24e7:89
    close @ Userform.vue?6370:412
    eval @ Userform.vue?6370:440
    Promise.then (async)
    submit @ Userform.vue?6370:437
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
    Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888
    click @ VBtn.ts?0eff:156
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
    original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        at VueComponent.uploadref (Userform.vue?6370:361)
        at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
        at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175)
        at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
        at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888)
        at VueComponent.set [as internalValue] (VFileInput.ts?e8de:108)
        at VueComponent.reset (index.ts?91bf:220)
        at eval (VForm.ts?24e7:89)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at VueComponent.reset (VForm.ts?24e7:89)
```

I also get the same error if I try to clear the file upload and select a new file without submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work in this case. The problem seems to be that when the form is cleared it activates the onChange event again in the v-file-input. Since the input is cleared by the form reset, the data becomes undefined and when sent to the upload function it causes the error.

I added a check to see if the data file (referencefile) was undefined before executing the upload function.

```
if (this.referencefile !== undefined){
  // execute the upload
}
```